# Xarray don't append dimension when concatenating datasets

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

I've got two datasets that I want to concatenate. They each contain two arrays, a two dimensional *intensity* array (dims = time * wavelength) and an unrelated 1D array with *channel names*, which is the same in both datasets. When I concatenate along the time dimension, an extra time dimension is added to the channel names array. This makes somewhat sense, and is also mentioned in the documentation, but I would like the channel names to remain the same in the result. How can I prevent this extra dimension?

The following example demonstrates what I want.

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

DIM_TIME = "time"
DIM_CHANNEL_NR = 'channel_number'
DIM_WAVELENGTH = "wavelength"

def create_ds(intensity, time_local):
    wavelength = np.linspace(700.0, 800.0, 8)

    da_wav = xr.DataArray(wavelength, dims=[DIM_WAVELENGTH])
    da_time = xr.DataArray(time_local, dims=[DIM_TIME])
    da_chan_nr = xr.DataArray(np.array([1, 2]), dims=[DIM_CHANNEL_NR])

    da_intensity = xr.DataArray(
        intensity, name='intensity',
        dims=[DIM_TIME, DIM_WAVELENGTH],
        coords={DIM_TIME: da_time, DIM_WAVELENGTH: da_wav})

    da_chan_name = xr.DataArray(
        data = np.array(['UV', 'VIS']),
        name = 'chan_name',
        dims = [DIM_CHANNEL_NR])

    ds = xr.Dataset(
        data_vars={da_intensity.name: da_intensity},
        coords={
            DIM_TIME: da_time,
            DIM_WAVELENGTH: da_wav,
            DIM_CHANNEL_NR: da_chan_nr})

    ds[da_chan_name.name] = da_chan_name
    return ds

def main():
    ds1 = create_ds(
        intensity=np.arange(24).reshape((3, 8)),
        time_local = np.array([1e17, 2e17, 3e17]).astype('datetime64[ns]'))

    ds2 = create_ds(
        intensity=np.arange(24).reshape((3, 8)) + 24,
        time_local = np.array([4e17, 5e17, 6e17]).astype('datetime64[ns]'))

    print("---- concat ----\n{}\n".format(xr.concat([ds1, ds2], dim=DIM_TIME)))
    print("---- merged ----\n{}\n".format(xr.merge([ds1, ds2])))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run this, the concatenated dataset looks like this.

```
---- concat ----
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (time: 6, wavelength: 8, channel_number: 2)
Coordinates:
  * time            (time) datetime64[ns] 1973-03-03T09:46:40 ... 1989-01-05T...
  * wavelength      (wavelength) float64 700.0 714.3 728.6 ... 771.4 785.7 800.0
  * channel_number  (channel_number) int32 1 2
Data variables:
    intensity       (time, wavelength) int32 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 42 43 44 45 46 47
    chan_name       (time, channel_number) <U3 'UV' 'VIS' 'UV' ... 'UV' 'VIS'
```

As you can see, the `chan_name` array is now two dimensional; the `time` dimension has been prepended.

When I merge the datasets, the result is exactly as I want it:

```
---- merged ----
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:         (time: 6, wavelength: 8, channel_number: 2)
Coordinates:
  * time            (time) datetime64[ns] 1973-03-03T09:46:40 ... 1989-01-05T...
  * wavelength      (wavelength) float64 700.0 714.3 728.6 ... 771.4 785.7 800.0
  * channel_number  (channel_number) int32 1 2
Data variables:
    intensity       (time, wavelength) float64 0.0 1.0 2.0 ... 45.0 46.0 47.0
    chan_name       (channel_number) <U3 'UV' 'VIS'
```

Here the `chan_name` array remains the same as in the original datasets, a one-dimensional array.

Unfortunately, `xr.merge` is much slower than `xr.concat`. It there a way to concatenate that leaves unrelated arrays in tact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
print("---- concat ----\n{}\n".format(xr.concat([ds1, ds2], dim=DIM_TIME, data_vars="minimal")))
```

Comment: This works. Thanks a lot. I must say that the [documentation](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.concat.html) is unclear to me. It says *“minimal”: Only data variables in which the dimension already appears are included*. I read this as that the `chan_name` array would be omitted in the result.